# How to handle global config without magic mode?

Tags: ractivejs

From v0.9 the "magic mode" is removed.
How should we now handle scenarios like in this sample:

Updating all the prices when global config with rates updated
http://jsfiddle.net/Inversion/7an5hdb5/

```
conf =
    g_currency_exchange_rates:
        usd:27

win.r = new Ractive
    el: 'cont'
    template: '#tpl'
    magic:true
    data:
        conf:conf
        items_prices_usd: [5, 10, 25]
        in_uah: (v)-> v * @get 'conf.g_currency_exchange_rates.usd'

update_rate = ->
    conf.g_currency_exchange_rates.usd += Math.round(Math.random()*2-1)
setInterval update_rate, 500
```

In the sample there is only one Ractive instance, but imagine you have several different on the page and all they use same config and should dynamically update any rate changes. And they really should be separate root instances, not nested components.
For example if you are logged in as admin — admin panel can be shown on demand, and it is like another app, but relies on the same config.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reference to the instance, you can call `ractive.update()` after setting new data.

https://jsfiddle.net/artvhvpo/

```
console.clear();win=window

conf =
    g_currency_exchange_rates:
        usd:27

win.r = new Ractive
    el: 'cont'
    template: '#tpl'
    magic:true
    data:
        conf:conf
        items_prices_usd: [5, 10, 25]
        in_uah: (v)-> v * @get 'conf.g_currency_exchange_rates.usd'

update_rate = ->
    conf.g_currency_exchange_rates.usd += Math.round(Math.random()*2-1);win.r.update()
setInterval update_rate, 500
```

Comment: Yes, but what if there are many Ractive instances and many different conf properties can be changed. 
Magic mode controlled everything for me, so I didn't have to remember where to put those updates and for what — that is the point.